# NodeJs Mssql Timeout

Tags: node.js, sql-server, timeout

well i'll try to be as short as possibile.
This code gives me a Connection error that sais :

ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost\SQLMAD in 15000ms

You'd say: it could happen and i'd say: it worked until today morning...so i started wondering what's the problem...anyway...here's my code:

```
    var sql = require("mssql");
    var dbConfig = {
        server: "localhost\\SQLMAD",  
        database: "Dymosoft",        
        user: "sa",          
        password: "LeenoxDays7@",    
        port: "65401"                
   };
   var fs = require('fs');


    function connect(dbInitializer){
        dbInitializer = dbConfig;
        var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbInitializer);               
        var req = new sql.Request(conn);                                
            conn.connect(function(err){                                 
            if(err){                                        
                console.log(err);                                       
                return;                                                 
            } 
            else{
                var str_backup = "select * from utenti;" 
                console.log(str_backup);    
                req.query(str_backup,function(err, recordset){      
                    if(err){                                        
                        console.log(err);                           
                        return;
                    }
                    else{
                      console.log(recordset);                       
                    }
                    conn.close();
                });
            }
        });}
```

I checked my services to see if the sqlBrowser was started, then i went my sqlServer configuration manager to check if tcp/ip was enabled (it was).
So i started wondering what's the problem?!

For more details (i know it's in italian but you can easly figure out what the labels actually mean):
[image]

Thanks in advance for answers

Comment: So you try to connect locally, don't you? Please try .\SQLMAD (by the way, when connect locally you don't use tcp\ip if not set explicitely, so you are using Shared Memory)

Comment: Another thing to exclude..Are you sure your server is running?

Comment: Only now I noted that your connection string contains port number, in this case you are using tcp\ip BUT you don't use SQL Server Browser, niether SQL Server instance name, all that is uses is localhost,65401. You should check is your server effectively uses 65401 (open error log and fing the effective port there), and try to use your pc name instead of localhost

Comment: Well should i remove the port from my config? or it's just useless since my connection doesn't really uses that parameter?! 

I'm sure my server is running because i'm actually connected with sql management studio and i can see the service is running from "services"

note : i'm trying right now to user .\SQLMAD 

Thanks for now dude, i'll keep you up to date

Comment: >>>or it's just useless since my connection doesn't really uses that parameter?! <<< When the port is specified, the PORT is using (as well as tcp\ip), instance name is just ignored, that is why SQL Server Browser does not partecipate in this case

Comment: Well it strangely seems to work again. 
I tried to: 
- remove port from configurations (no appearing changes) 
- check if shared memory was enabled (it was)
- restart SqlServer service 
- disable firewall for private network 
- disconnect from my hotspot
- restarted my Sql Browser service
I tried again and it worked.
- Then i switched on my firewall (kept working)
- Reconnected to my hotspost  - clearly it doesn't affect my connection but you never know ...kinda like blowing on usb cables  (kept working)

So i can't figure out what was happening..any idea?

Comment: Can you check your last(not current) error log for any errors?

Comment: My last log ( well...the log i was "writing" when i asked this questions) doesn't say that much regarding my connections. The only strange thing reported is : 

2018-09-21 12:38:45.39 Server      The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/DESKTOP-GH0PVGI:60936 ] for the SQL Server service. Windows return code: 0xffffffff, state: 63. This is an informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies and if the SPN has not been manually registered.

Comment: No, this error ( if you found it in previous error log, you'll find it iin every error log) has nothing to do with "server not found", the strange thing is it's reporting a DIFFERENT port number, 60936. So that time your server was using this port, this can explain why the server was not found on the port 65401.

Comment: Well i found that whatever port i specify it doesn't affect in any manner my connection since i'm trying to use the port "11111". 
I'm passing the dbConfig value set as follow:  dbConfig = {
             server: "localhost\\sqlMad",  //server e istanza..il doppio slash se no fa l'escape e sparisce
             database: "Demetra",   //chiaramente il nome del database
             user: "sa",    //utente
             password: "LeenoxDays7@",
             port: '11111'
          }
          return dbConfig;
      };
 and it keeps working.

I can't really figure it out lol

Comment: Ho capito del doppio slash, ciao da Roma :) But this means the only thing: you are connecting via shared memory, i.e. the port is not considered at all in your connection string. Generally, it works viceversa: if the port is specified, instance name is ignored, I mean, if you pass in pcname\bla-bla-bla,65401 it still connects because when the port is specified there is no need in instance name so it is happily ignored and SQL Server Browser is NOT asked for the port, and tcp\ip is used

Comment: Era un commento del codice che mi sono portato dietro nel copia incolla haha anyway i got what you're saying and it actually makes sense to me. Thanks for you support and your help. Saluti da Lucca :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this Out!!

```
    var dbConfig = {
    server: "127.0.0.1",  
    database: "Dymosoft",        
    user: "sa",          
    password: "LeenoxDays7@",    
    port: "65401"
```

};

and please check the username and password

Comment: User and psw are right...i'll try to use 127.0.0.1 even if it should work even with localhost (i suppose, am i wrong?) ..thanks for now

Comment: >>>and please check the username and password<<< It's NOT username and password because he has no response from server, server is not found